# Generate session against CNIC Number and expire it after 5 minutes of inactivity and redirect the user to Homepage

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core MVC application and I want that on the `Homepage` the user will be required to enter his/her CNIC (Identity Card) number.

After that, he'll be able to navigate to any page on the application. But if he/she is idle for 5 minutes or more then after 5 minutes if he/she tries to perform any action means to try to go to any other page then he/she will be redirected to "Homepage" and is required to enter his/her CNIC number again.

How can I implement this functionality using Sessions in the an ASP.NET Core MVC application?

Thank you

Comment: Did you mean that you want a "Filter" to intercept all actions and check if the session is expired first then decide whether to redirect or not?

Comment: Exactly, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me post a sample, it's just a sample but it worked for me.

Fisrtly, I have a controller home action which will store a session. In your scenario, you have to store the session according to what users entered.

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var value = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Code");
            if (value == null) {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("Code", "001");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Then I created an action filter to intercept all the requests, the filter should check if the incoming request is direct to the home page and whether there's a session value. So the filter should look like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace WebMvcNet3.Filters
{
    public class SessionFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var value = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Code");
            var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (value == null && path != "/Home/Index") {
                context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index");
                context.Result.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            // Do something after the action executes.
        }
    }
}
```

Then register the filter in startup.cs, and pls don't forget to add `app.UseSession();` in Configure method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSession(options => {
        //options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    });
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddScoped<SessionFilter>();
    services.AddControllers(config =>
    {
        config.Filters.Add<SessionFilter>();
    });
}
```

Comment: I have done everything else. Just one last thing how to activate a session when a user clicks the login button and is logged in successfully?

Comment: How you deal with the click event of the `login` button? send a request to your backend and validate the user name and password? Then active the session after the user passed validation. If the sign in module is provided by some other libraries e.g. azure ad, then you may have to send an ajax request after the signed in model redirect to your own page.